# CamelCase to underscores and back in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I'm looking for a simple, efficient way to convert strings in CamelCase to underscore notation (i.e., MyClassName -> my_class_name) and back again in Objective C.

My current solution involves lots of `rangeOfString`, `characterAtIndex`, and `replaceCharactersInRange` operations on NSMutableStrings, and is just plain ugly as hell :) It seems that there must be a better solution, but I'm not sure what it is.

I'd rather not import a regex library just for this one use case, though that is an option if all else fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chris's suggestion of RegexKitLite is good. It's an excellent toolkit, but this could be done pretty easily with [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Use `-scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:` alternating between `+uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` and `+lowercaseLetterCharacterSet`. For going back, you'd use `-scanUpToCharactersFromSet:` instead, using a character set with just an underscore in it.

Comment: Thanks Rob -- my lack of experience using NSScanner is what made me overlook this solution, but it is a lot cleaner than what I had.

Answer (score 9):

How about these:

```
NSString *MyCamelCaseToUnderscores(NSString *input) {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    NSCharacterSet *uppercase = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < [input length]; idx += 1) {
        unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:idx];
        if ([uppercase characterIsMember:c]) {
            [output appendFormat:@"_%@", [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString]];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%C", c];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

NSString *MyUnderscoresToCamelCase(NSString *underscores) {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    BOOL makeNextCharacterUpperCase = NO;
    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < [underscores length]; idx += 1) {
        unichar c = [underscores characterAtIndex:idx];
        if (c == '_') {
            makeNextCharacterUpperCase = YES;
        } else if (makeNextCharacterUpperCase) {
            [output appendString:[[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] uppercaseString]];
            makeNextCharacterUpperCase = NO;
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%C", c];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Some drawbacks are that they do use temporary strings to convert between upper and lower case, and they don't have any logic for acronyms, so myURL will result in my_u_r_l.

Answer (score 9):

Try this magic:

```
NSString* camelCaseString = @"myBundleVersion";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])|([A-Z])(?=[a-z])" options:0 error:nil];
NSString *underscoreString = [[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:camelCaseString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, camelCaseString.length) withTemplate:@"_$1$2"] lowercaseString];
NSLog(@"%@", underscoreString);
```

Output: my_bundle_version

Comment: If the string is in Pascal case i.e. MyBundleVersion, it will produce _my_bundle_version

Comment: I would love to see a version with leading underscores fixed and one that converts the other way as well.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei it doesn't handle names like URLRequest.

Comment: My solution was simple `[underscoreString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_"]]`

Comment: @AntonMatosov, Your solution removes underscores, and doesn't transform a camel case string into an underscore string.

Comment: My line of code is addition to regex solution in this post. It just solves the problem of leading underscore.

Answer (score 4):

If your concern is just the visibility of your code, you could make a category for `NSString` using the methods you've designed already.  That way, you only see the ugly mess once. ;)

For instance:

```
@interface NSString(Conversions) {
     - (NSString *)asCamelCase;
     - (NSString *)asUnderscored;
}

@implementation NSString(Conversions) {
     - (NSString *)asCamelCase {
          // whatever you came up with
     }
     - (NSString *)asUnderscored {
          // whatever you came up with
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: After a quick Google search, I couldn't find any way of doing this, even in plain C.  However, I did find a framework that could be useful. It's called [RegexKitLite](http://peekay.org/2009/03/18/iphone-sdk-regular-expressions/). It uses the built-in ICU library, so it only adds about 20K to the final binary.

Comment: Chris, thanks much for the RegexKitLite pointer. I'm definitely going to use it in future projects!

Comment: It's about 100,000 years later than when this answer was posted in iOS development terms; should anybody else stumble in here: don't use RegexKitLite. `NSRegularExpression` turned up in iOS 4, about six months after this answer was posted, bringing the same ICU library into the standard frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my implementation of Rob's answer:

```
@implementation NSString (CamelCaseConversion)

// Convert a camel case string into a dased word sparated string.
// In case of scanning error, return nil.
// Camel case string must not start with a capital.
- (NSString *)fromCamelCaseToDashed {

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
    scanner.caseSensitive = YES;

    NSString *builder = [NSString string];
    NSString *buffer = nil;
    NSUInteger lastScanLocation = 0;

    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] intoString:&buffer]) {

            builder = [builder stringByAppendingString:buffer];

            if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] intoString:&buffer]) {

                builder = [builder stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
                builder = [builder stringByAppendingString:[buffer lowercaseString]];
            }
        }

        // If the scanner location has not moved, there's a problem somewhere.
        if (lastScanLocation == scanner.scanLocation) return nil;
        lastScanLocation = scanner.scanLocation;
    }

    return builder;
}

@end
```

Comment: why not use a NSMutableString as builder?

Comment: Would be better, indeed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's yet another version based on all the above. This version handles additional forms. In particular, tested with the following:

```
camelCase => camel_case
camelCaseWord => camel_case_word
camelURL => camel_url
camelURLCase => camel_url_case
CamelCase => camel_case
```

Here goes

```
- (NSString *)fromCamelCaseToDashed3 {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    NSCharacterSet *uppercase = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
    BOOL previousCharacterWasUppercase = FALSE;
    BOOL currentCharacterIsUppercase = FALSE;
    unichar currentChar = 0;
    unichar previousChar = 0;
    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < [self length]; idx += 1) {
        previousChar = currentChar;
        currentChar = [self characterAtIndex:idx];
        previousCharacterWasUppercase = currentCharacterIsUppercase;
        currentCharacterIsUppercase = [uppercase characterIsMember:currentChar];

        if (!previousCharacterWasUppercase && currentCharacterIsUppercase && idx > 0) {
            // insert an _ between the characters
            [output appendString:@"_"];
        } else if (previousCharacterWasUppercase && !currentCharacterIsUppercase) {
            // insert an _ before the previous character
            // insert an _ before the last character in the string
            if ([output length] > 1) {
                unichar charTwoBack = [output characterAtIndex:[output length]-2];
                if (charTwoBack != '_') {
                    [output insertString:@"_" atIndex:[output length]-1];
                }
            }
        } 
        // Append the current character lowercase
        [output appendString:[[NSString stringWithCharacters:&currentChar length:1] lowercaseString]];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned with the speed of your code you probably want to write a more performant version of the code:

```
- (nonnull NSString *)camelCaseToSnakeCaseString {
    if ([self length] == 0) {
        return @"";
    }
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    NSCharacterSet *digitSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *uppercaseSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *lowercaseSet = [NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet];

    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < [self length]; idx += 1) {
        unichar c = [self characterAtIndex:idx];

        // if it's the last one then just append lowercase of character
        if (idx == [self length] - 1) {
            if ([uppercaseSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                [output appendFormat:@"%@", [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString]];
            }
            else {
                [output appendFormat:@"%C", c];
            }
            continue;
        }

        unichar nextC = [self characterAtIndex:(idx+1)];
        // this logic finds the boundaries between lowercase/uppercase/digits and lets the string be split accordingly.
        if ([lowercaseSet characterIsMember:c] && [uppercaseSet characterIsMember:nextC]) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%@_", [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString]];
        }
        else if ([lowercaseSet characterIsMember:c] && [digitSet characterIsMember:nextC]) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%@_", [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString]];
        }
        else if ([digitSet characterIsMember:c] && [uppercaseSet characterIsMember:nextC]) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%@_", [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString]];
        }
        else {
            // Append lowercase of character
            if ([uppercaseSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                [output appendFormat:@"%@", [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] lowercaseString]];
            }
            else {
                [output appendFormat:@"%C", c];
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have combined the answers found here into my refactoring library, [es_ios_utils](https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils).  See [NSCategories.h](https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils/blob/master/es_ios_utils/ESNSCategories.h):

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *asCamelCaseFromUnderscores;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *asUnderscoresFromCamelCase;
```

Usage:

```
@"my_string".asCamelCaseFromUnderscores
```

yields @"myString"

Please push improvements!

Answer (score 0):

I happened upon this question looking for a way to convert Camel Case to a spaced, user displayable string.  Here is my solution which worked better than replacing @"_" with @" "

```
- (NSString *)fromCamelCaseToSpaced:(NSString*)input {
    NSCharacterSet* lower = [NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet* upper = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];

    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        if ([upper characterIsMember:[input characterAtIndex:i]] &&
            [lower characterIsMember:[input characterAtIndex:i-1]])
        {
            NSString* soFar = [input substringToIndex:i];
            NSString* left = [input substringFromIndex:i];
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", soFar, [self fromCamelCaseToSpaced:left]];
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Looks already pretty good, but: 1. what if input is null? 2. how does the conversion back work? 3. couldn't your loop start with `i = 1` making the `i > 1`obsolete?

Comment: 1.  If input is nil then nil is returned as the length message sent to nil will return 0
2. Good point, I didn't need this in my app
3. I like that, edited it into my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK guys. Here is an all regex answer, which I consider the only true way:

Given:

```
NSString *MYSTRING = "foo_bar";

NSRegularExpression *_toCamelCase = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(_)([a-z])" 
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *camelCaseAttribute = [_toCamelCase 
    stringByReplacingMatchesInString:MYSTRING options:0 
    range:NSMakeRange(0, attribute.length) 
    withTemplate:@"\\U$2"];
```

Yields **fooBar**.

Conversely:

```
NSString *MYSTRING = "fooBar";


NSRegularExpression *camelCaseTo_ = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([A-Z])" 
    options:0 error:&error];

NSString *underscoreParsedAttribute = [camelCaseTo_ 
    stringByReplacingMatchesInString:MYSTRING 
    options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, attribute.length) 
    withTemplate:@"_$1"];
underscoreParsedAttribute = [underscoreParsedAttribute lowercaseString];
```

Yields: **foo_bar**.

\U$2 replaces second capture group with upper-case version of itself :D

\L$1 however, oddly, does not replace the first capture group with a lower-case version of itself :( Not sure why, it should work. :/