# Add space in string before each word

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am looking for an elegant (at least a clean) way to add space between each word in a camel cased sentence.

Example `ThisIsASentence` should be transformed in `This Is A Sentence`

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways to do this: use a regular expression (`NSRegularExpression`) which matches a lowercase letter (or not an uppercase letter if you've got non-letters in the string) followed by an uppercase one and replaces them with the two matched characters with a space between them - i.e. exactly how you'd solve this problem in a decent text editor (TextWrangler *et.al.*)

If you have trouble implementing the code ask a new question showing your code and explaining your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with regular expression, it considers only the uppercase characters `A-Z`.

The regex pattern `(?<!^)[A-Z]` searches for a single uppercase character which is not the beginning of the string.

```
NSMutableString *camelCaseString = @"ThisIsASentence".mutableCopy;
NSString *pattern = @"(?<!^)[A-Z]";
NSRegularExpression *regex =  [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:camelCaseString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, camelCaseString.length) withTemplate:@" $0"];
NSLog(@"%@", camelCaseString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but regex are something I would like to avoid for such a simple thing.

Comment: You wrote *elegant* and *clean* ;-)

Comment: Finally I've just found this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918972/camelcase-to-underscores-and-back-in-objective-c seems to do the job